# the constant time_base in output AVStream

Tags: ffmpeg

When we want to mux audio and video into OutputContext, we must convert the time_base of AVPacekt. What I confused is why the time_base of output AVStream is (1, 90000)? For some historical reasons or another?

Answer (score 2):

Streaming video codecs typically use a `90 Khz` (`1 / 90000`) clock rate, or a higher frequency that is backwards compatible with this one, like the `27 MHz = 300 * 90 Khz` clock in `MPEG-2`.

For `MPEG-1` the value was chosen in accordance with a digital video standard recommendation from the 80's called the `ITU-R` (ex `CCIR`) `601` which was suitable for use with the `625/50 Hz` and `525/60 Hz` modes used in `PAL`/`NTSC` analogue broadcasts.

Using the sampling frequency for luminance (`Y`) of `13.5 Mhz` from the aforementioned guideline they decided to use a `13.5 Mhz / 150 = 90 Khz` value which provided a good enough accuracy for decoding/presentation timestamps.

Source: *Fundamentals and Evolution of MPEG-2 Systems: Paving the MPEG Road*, Jan Van der Meer

Comment: *majority of video codecs* --> doesn't appear to be default for most codecs or containers. Not for MP4/MOV/MKV..etc

Comment: @Mulvya I was thinking *streaming* codecs, but you're right it's misleading.